# Why does Ionic 2 CLI print extraneous data?

Tags: ionic2

I'm running Ionic 2.0.0.-beta3.2 and Node 6.2.1.

When I run `ionic build <platform>` or `ionic run <platform>`, the CLI will print extraneous like what follows below. Why?

0=82, 1=117, 2=110, 3=110, 4=105, 5=110, 6=103, 7=32, 8=99, 9=111, 10=109, 11=109, 12=97, 13=110, 14=100, 15=58, 16=32, 17=47, 18=85, 19=115, 20=101, 21=114, 22=115, 23=47, 24=106, 25=101, 26=102, 27=102, 28=114, 29=101, 30=121, 31=114, 32=105, 33=99, 34=104, 35=97, 36=114, 37=100, 38=115, 39=111, 40=110, 41=47, 42=87, 43=104, 44=105, 45=114, 46=108, 47=112, 48=111, 49=111, 50=108, 51=77, 52=111, 53=98, 54=105, 55=108, 56=101, 57=65, 58=112, 59=112, 60=108, 61=105, 62=99, 63=97, 64=116, 65=105, 66=111, 67=110, 68=47, 69=87, 70=72, 71=82, 72=65, 73=80, 74=80, 75=47, 76=104, 77=111, 78=111, 79=107, 80=115, 81=47, 82=97, 83=102, 84=116, 85=101, 86=114, 87=95, 88=112, 89=114, 90=101, 91=112, 92=97, 93=114, 94=101, 95=47, 96=48, 97=49, 98=48, 99=95, 100=97, 101=100, 102=100, 103=95, 104=112, 105=108, 106=97, 107=116, 108=102, 109=111, 110=114, 111=109, 112=95, 113=99, 114=108, 115=97, 116=115, 117=115, 118=46, 119=106, 120=115, 121=32, 122=47, 123=85, 124=115, 125=101, 126=114, 127=115, 128=47, 129=106, 130=101, 131=102, 132=102, 133=114, 134=101, 135=121, 136=114, 137=105, 138=99, 139=104, 140=97, 141=114, 142=100, 143=115, 144=111, 145=110, 146=47, 147=87, 148=104, 149=105, 150=114, 151=108, 152=112, 153=111, 154=111, 155=108, 156=77, 157=111, 158=98, 159=105, 160=108, 161=101, 162=65, 163=112, 164=112, 165=108, 166=105, 167=99, 168=97, 169=116, 170=105, 171=111, 172=110, 173=47, 174=87, 175=72, 176=82, 177=65, 178=80, 179=80